# How to find particular data from an API in XML format to a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, google-api, xml-parsing

I'm trying to access all the ratings (12 ratings in this particular URL) from Google Places API add store them in an array so I can calculate the average rating and show it in an HTML textbox. This is on an html page in a Spring boot applications. However, I'm getting an error in my Eclipse prompt like so:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

And an error in my browser that says (Will highlight in code snippet):

```
Exception parsing document: template="index", line 203 - column 23
```

Im lost as to where the error is coming from, is it a problem with passing the variables into the url, or is this method of parsing just doing what I think its doing? I've been researching many questions on StackOverflow and trying to implement those answers all day but no joy.

```
function getCafe(){

   // Lat and Long values provided by user on a Google Map
   $('.search_latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
   $('.search_longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());

   var Lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
   var Long = marker.getPosition().lng();
   var cafeRatings = [];
   var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location="+ Lat + "," + Long + "&amp;radius=500&amp;type=restaurant&amp;keyword=cruise&amp;key=MY_API_KEY";


   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("GET", url, false);
   request.send();
   var xml = request.responseXML;
   var results = xml.getElementsByTagName("result");
   for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { <--- Error in browser points to this line (line 203)
       var result = results[i];
       var ratings = result.getElementsByTagName("rating");
       for(var j = 0; j < ratings.length; j++) {
           alert(ratings[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
           cafeRatings.push(ratings);
       }
   }

   // Displaying contents of the array as a simple debug
   window.alert(cafeRatings);

}
```

This is the XML formatted API I'm trying to access where the "Rating" value is what I'm trying to access.

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>OK</status>


 <result>
         <name>Sydney Showboats</name>
         <vicinity>32 The Promenade, Sydney</vicinity>
         <type>travel_agency</type>
         <type>restaurant</type>
         <type>food</type>
         <type>point_of_interest</type>
         <type>establishment</type>
    <geometry>
        <location>
        <lat>-33.8675570</lat>
        <lng>151.2015270</lng>
        </location>
          <viewport>
           <southwest>
             <lat>-33.8689120</lat>
             <lng>151.2001126</lng>
           </southwest>
           <northeast>
             <lat>-33.8662141</lat>
             <lng>151.2028105</lng>
           </northeast>
          </viewport>
    </geometry>
    <rating>3.8</rating> <------ This is the element im trying to ad to the array
    <icon>
    https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png
    </icon>
    <reference>
    CmRSAAAALItuCtuLapozzsjq3dmKqj7NDik149XsgUwHD3ob5AWfHYlZtykuJbQa0cq0GMqX8dRgucTCmitnXgV-ekE3GfV7910rzHhx3ZuadVYNuWMzLDVZDCj2G1yiBw8r_hhgEhCPDXsniaZ2ZrkvYyXFfmQrGhSzdmkAEz4stXNx2qFe-GqAlldzgw
    </reference>
    <id>ce4ffe228ab7ad49bb050defe68b3d28cc879c4a</id>
    <opening_hours>
    <open_now>false</open_now>
    </opening_hours>
    <photo>
    <photo_reference>
    CmRaAAAAh4dP9hsZ_6515QNxouVnuYFYKemmf8BE01rcaOvkFlILQiwGNe_OAX0ikmobMmWZJvyjsFEsn7j1TFhauHSrek8nY5GsW24_6nwJsqEwHTUC10SL5gQITHhkdam50G1PEhCP-C7Of2mkjqJCTYFeYGWuGhQjVoWASHiGSp3WHm26Bh2sYOglZw
    </photo_reference>
    <width>2048</width>
    <height>1152</height>
    <html_attribution>
    <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107415973755376511005/photos">Sydney Showboats</a>
    </html_attribution>
    </photo>
    <place_id>ChIJjRuIiTiuEmsRCHhYnrWiSok</place_id>
    <scope>GOOGLE</scope>
    </result>
........
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery have the $.ajax() tool, try using this one for apis